# Pandas correlation matrix not incorporating all columns in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, analytics

I have a csv file consisting of 12 data columns and want to create a correlation matrix with them. However, when doing this using pandas, only 4 (seemingly random) columns are incorporated. Any ideas why the remaining columns don't make it into the correlation matrix?

```
d = pd.read_csv('national_raw_convictions.csv')
cm = d.corr().abs()
cm.to_csv('national_raw_convictions_correlation.csv')
```

I have attached a screenshot of both the input (left) and output (right) csv files referenced. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNBHW.png)

Comment: Can you print the d.info()? It's probably because some data are not loaded as numeric

Comment: The `pd.corr()` only shows the correlation between variables that are classified as int or float. Could you check the type of each column?

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough info to be sure.

My guess would be that columns have an object data type. While reading data, pandas try its best to understand columns data type. But if for some reason column has numbers and strings, column data type will be 'object'.
To check dataframe data types, you can run `d.dtypes`.

Hope it could help.

Comment: Genius!! Thank you, yeah after checking this is the exact issue. Any idea on how I would go about changing the data types from object to int64??

Comment: Pandas has `astype` method. Still,  it is always better to check what are non-numeric samples in the column and why so.